# Wordpress Events Manager Plugin adding new events not working

Tags: wordpress, events, content-management-system

i download 'Events Manager' plugin to create events 
its working perfectly in localhost but 
when i tried to use in server i got this errror

**Your event details are incorrect and cannot be published, please correct these errors first:
Something went wrong saving your event to the index table. Please inform a site administrator about this.**

Comment: Make sure that, event tables are proper install in your database...

Comment: yes i checked and noticed in my localhost database has six extra tables with prefix wp_em_ but it doesn't have in server; so i thought its wp-config access issue i had set only rewrite permission in wp-config so ichanged to as dba but no result

Comment: just export your local database and import in your server...

And don't forgot to replace `siteurl` with your server url...may be that will works...